# Combinatorics of pairs

Tags: combinatorics

Is it possible to order the pairs:
$$(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,2)$$
$$(2,2),(2,2),(2,3),(2,3)$$
$$(3,3),(3,3),(3,4),(3,4)$$
$$(4,4),(4,4),(4,1),(4,1)$$

into 4 groups of 4 pairs, such that in each group has only unique number for the first and second values

-> (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4) is valid

-> (1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(4,1) isnt valid

additionally, when writing out the groups in a single line, is there a way to configure the groups in such a way, that if you shift the grouping by two, the property is still kept?

I haven't been able to find an example, but i came really close:

$(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(4,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)$

grouping 1)

$[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)],[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)],[(4,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)],[(4,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]$

grouping 2)

$(1,1),(2,2)],[(3,3),(4,4),(1,1),(2,2)],[(3,3),(4,4),(4,1),(1,2)],[(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(1,2)],[(2,3),(3,4) $

If there is no way to do this properly, why?

I am also very sorry, if the wording on this is wrong or not understandable, but I would appreciate an answer to this question. If anything is unclear, please leave a question and I will try and clarify as soon as I can.

Comment: Aren't the columns in your first display such a grouping?

Comment: Omg, I'm blind lol. Thank you so much.

Comment: It happens.  Glad to help!

Comment: ahhh, no actually. The groupings are supposed to be circular. this means that after the shift the first and last group are joined into a new group:
for the columns, that last group would be (3,4),(4,1),(1,1),(2,2), but then there is (4,1) and (1,1) with the same number

Comment: I'm not convinced I understand this constraint at all.